# Django Rest Framework is it possible to serialize a geojson from a query using a geometry_field via foreignkey?

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, geojson, geodjango

I have two models: one to maintain a grid of points and a second one to save geospatial data

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models as geomodels
from django.db import models

class Grid(geomodels.Model):

    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=4326, unique=True)
    elevation = geomodels.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class SpData(models.Model):

    mtime = models.DateTimeField()
    grid = models.ForeignKey(Grid)
    measure = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=1,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
```

With django rest framework it's very easy to get a geojson file for a model
having a geometry field as my Grid model, and the following view provide a 
nice geojson with geom as geometry field and 'elevation' in properties.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import Grid

class GridView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        result = serialize(
            "geojson",
            Grid.objects.all(),
            geometry_field="geom",
            srid=4326,
            fields=(
                "elevation",
            ),
        )

        return HttpResponse(result)
```

Now I want to use the same grid to display the SpData records that are linked to 
my Grid model to display the 'measure' value, but I do not succeed to indicate 
to the serializer that I want to use the geometry of the Grid table. I thought 
that such elegant code could work:

```
class SpDataView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        geodata = SpData.objects.filter(mtime=today())
        fields = ("measure", "grid",)
        result = serialize(
            "geojson",
            geodata,
            geometry_field="grid.geom",
            srid=4326,
            fields=fields,
            use_natural_foreign_keys=True,
        )

        return HttpResponse(result)
```

But it does not. So, I've tried to add a property field to my SpData model but it does not work either:

```
class SpData(models.Model):

    mtime = models.DateTimeField()
    grid = models.ForeignKey(Grid)
    measure = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=1,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    @property
    def geom(self):
        return self.grid.geom


class SpDataView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        geodata = SpData.objects.filter(mtime=today())
        fields = ("measure", "geom",)
        result = serialize(
            "geojson",
            geodata,
            geometry_field="geom",
            srid=4326,
            fields=fields,
        )

        return HttpResponse(result)
```

I've tried to use a raw SQL query, but serializer only consider fields of the 
model on which the raw sql has been done.

```
strsql ='SELECT sp.pk, sp.measure, g.geom '
strsql += ' FROM SpData AS sp'
strsql += ' INNER JOIN Grid AS g'
strsql += ' ON sp.grid = g.pk'
strsql += ' WHERE sp.mtime = today()'

geodata = SpData.objects.raw(strsql)
fields = ("measure", "geom",)
result = serialize(
    "geojson",
    geodata,
    geometry_field="geom",
    srid=4326,
    fields=fields,
)

return HttpResponse(result)
```

But geometry in my resulting geojson is equal to null. So reverting the SQL will 
provide a geometry but will not add the field 'measure' into properties:

```
strsql ='SELECT g.pk, sp.measure, g.geom '
strsql += ' FROM Grid AS g'
strsql += ' INNER JOIN SpData AS sp'
strsql += ' ON sp.grid = g.pk'
strsql += ' WHERE sp.mtime = today()'

geodata = Grid.objects.raw(strsql)
```

What am I missing? Is this out of scope of the current geodjango serializer?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to new links appearing in the related column I've understood what was
wrong with my assumptions, and finally I've found 2 solutions :
the first one creating a dedicated serializer,
the second one using an sqlview as model.

A) Creating a dedicated serializer redefining the get_properties method
to fill them with the desired measures :

```
from rest_framework_gis.serializers import GeoFeatureModelSerializer
from django.db import connection

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    """
    When using a django.db.connection for raw sql,
    returns all rows from a cursor as a dict
    """
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

class SpDataSerializer(GeoFeatureModelSerializer):
    """
    Geojson Serializer for SpData
    """

    def get_properties(self, instance, fields):
        """
        Retrieve the measures linked to each grid point
        """
        strsql ='SELECT sp.measure '
        strsql += ' FROM SpData AS sp'
        strsql += ' WHERE sp.grid_id = %s'
        strsql += ' AND sp.mtime = today()'

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(strsql, [instance.id])
            properties = dictfetchall(cursor)

        return properties[0]

    class Meta:
        model = Grid
        geo_field = "geom"
        fields = ("id", "elevation")
```

Then a view that use it to generate the geojson:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView

class SpDataView(ListAPIView):

    serializer_class = SpatialWalSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # get the grid
        queryset = Grid.objects.all()

        return queryset
```

The limitation with this elegant solution is the amount of queries that are done
(one for each geometry selected in the Grid model) and so using time.

B) To gain on performances I have implemented the GridView solution
 (see my first question) but applying it to a model based on a database VIEW
 being inpired by https://blog.rescale.com/using-database-views-in-django-orm/:

```
BEGIN
;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS app_viewspdata
;
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW app_viewspdata AS
    SELECT sp.id
    , g.geom
    , g.elevation
    , sp.mtime
    , sp.measure
    FROM app_spdata AS sp
    INNER JOIN app_grid AS g
    ON g.id = sp.grid_id
;
COMMIT
;
```

Then I've created a new model :

```
class ViewSpData(geomodels.Model):

    geom = geomodels.PointField(srid=4326, unique=True)
    elevation = geomodels.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    mtime = models.DateTimeField()
    measure = models.DecimalField(
        max_digits=6,
        decimal_places=1,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    class Meta:
            managed = False
            db_table = 'app_viewspdata'
```

This model can be used to generate the geojson like that :

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.serializers import serialize
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from .models import ViewSpData

class ViewSpDataView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        result = serialize(
            "geojson",
            ViewSpData.objects.filter(mtime=today()),
            geometry_field="geom",
            srid=4326,
            fields=(
                "measure",
                "elevation",
            ),
        )

        return HttpResponse(result)
```

That's it.